# Orthogonal compact operators on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

How do I show that when $H$ is an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space we can find two compact positive operators $u,v$ with infinite dimensional image  and $u \perp v$?

This statement can be found at "The alternative Dunford-Pettis property in $C^*$-algebras and von Neumann preduals" by Bunce and Peralta.

Answer (score 5):

Wlog $H=\ell_2$, then consider
$$
u:\ell_2\to\ell_2:(x_1,\ldots,x_n,\ldots)\mapsto\left(\frac{1}{1}x_1,0,\frac{1}{3}x_3,0,\frac{1}{5}x_5,\ldots\right)
$$
$$
v:\ell_2\to\ell_2:(x_1,\ldots,x_n,\ldots)\mapsto\left(0,\frac{1}{2}x_2,0,\frac{1}{4}x_4,0,\frac{1}{6}x_6\ldots\right)
$$

Comment: why $u$ and $v$ are compact?

Comment: $u$ and $v$ are just multiplication operators by null sequences. Such multiplication operators are allways compact.